# It is not possible to compile well by using lombok

Tags: java, javac, lombok

Because I am Japanese, poor English is used. 
Please acknowledge it. 
It is not possible to compile well by using lombok. 
(source site is http://projectlombok.org/download.html)
Lombok installed Eclipse was compiled was decompiled with jad.

```
import java.sql.*;
import lombok.Cleanup;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        // Statement
        @Cleanup Statement cstmt = null;
        cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call 11111.22222(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        // Execute
        cstmt.executeBatch();
        //write file code goes here 
    }
}
```

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public class TEST
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    Connection conn = null;

    Statement cstmt = null;
    try { cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call 11111.22222(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

      cstmt.executeBatch();
    }
    finally
    {
      if (Collections.singletonList(cstmt).get(0) != null) cstmt.close();
    }
  }
}
```

In the compilation result of eclipse, I am a result wanting it.
but this under command line compiled result is not match eclipse's result
javac -cp lib\lombok.jar src\TEST.java

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TEST
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    throws Exception
  {
    Object localObject = null;

    CallableStatement localCallableStatement = null;
    localCallableStatement = localObject.prepareCall("{call 11111.22222(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

    localCallableStatement.executeBatch();
  }
}
```

I want to acquire same result of eclipse as the compilation result in execution in the command line. 
How should I do?

```
OS setting
jdk=1.5
eclipse
jdk=1.5
```

Comment: What does `javac -version` show?

Comment: javac -version　is result javac 1.5.0_22

Comment: what is the error message? →　no error message

Comment: B.T.W. I think you've used different source files in your question. The first uses a Statement and the second one a CallableStatement.

Answer (score 4):

Lombok requires JDK 1.6 to be used with `javac`. However, using Lombok from Eclipse is free of this limitation.

Comment: Is there a version of lombock to which jdk1.5 is obtained?

Comment: Do you know a similar library where statement and resultset are automatically shut?

Comment: No other libraries exist (because you _need_ a 'finally' which only lombok can get around), and there is no way to make lombok work with javac 1.5. Which has been end-of-lifed for quite a while now.